# How to Access Talend Cloud Webhook Header

Tags: webhooks, talend

I'm just starting to work with Webhooks in Talend cloud.
how do I access the webhook callback header?

So far I have successfully:

1. Created a job
2. Published the artifact to the cloud
3. configured the environment and engine
4. invoked the webhook from the command line with curl
5. Output the payload via the context.resource_webhook_payload variable

Answer (score 0):

I see my problem.  I'm still learning API calls and such and Smartsheet API indicated they would send Header attributes.
When in fact this is simply in the payload, not a separate header designation.

Sorry for the naive question.